# To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

In my ASP.NET WebForms page I have a Modal window that pops up. The javascript code for displaying this modal window is as follows:

```
function OpenMailAddressWin(subscriberContactRelationGid, routeId, btn) {
    window.showModalDialog("SubscriberSecondaryAddress.aspx" + BuildQueryStringValuesForSubscriber(subscriberContactRelationGid, routeId, returntxtReceiptDate().value), this, strWindowFeatures + ";scroll:no;dialogWidth:442px;dialogHeight:350px");
    location.reload(true);
}
```

After the modal window is closed I need to refresh the parent page (hence the location.reload(true); statement at the end) in order for alterations made in the modal window to take affect.

Now the thing is that sometimes (not every time, infuriatingly) when I close this modal window I get a warning popup which says:

" To display the webpage again, Internet Explorer needs to resend the information you've recently submitted.

If you were making a purchase, you should click Cancel to avoid a duplicate transaction. Otherwise, click Retry to display the webpage again."

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Is there any postback going on that could cause this message?

Comment: The message would suggest that the action that directed the user to the parent window was posted. Browsers will always warn the user if they are resending a post, as by definition the post verb causes something to change.

Maybe sometimes the user visits the page with a post, and sometimes they don't?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the double-submit problem in browsers.

When a page is loaded using POST request and you try to reload the page using `location.reload(true);`, the browser needs to send another POST request to the server and this may cause problems as POST is supposed to change state on the server. Therefore, the browser needs confirmation from the user. To solve this problem, we usually use [POST-REDIRECT-GET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern.

In your case, just simply using `location.href = location.href` should solve the problem as this will reload the page using GET.

Comment: in chrome : `location.reload(true);` works without re submiting.  I've just tried it...( in IE - it does asks again) +1

Comment: you can also use, location.assign(location.href);

Answer (score 4):

This occurs when you try to return `view(Model)` from your **POST** request. Actually you cannot return a view from **POST** request because returning a view is supposed to be a **GET** operation and it must be done under **GET** request.
So after posting your data successfully and saving the data in database , you have to use `ReturnToAction` in your controller and return your final view from that action method.

Also If you want to refresh your page, you must use `location.href = location.href` instead of `window.reload()`, because `location.href` will get the data through **GET** request.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `setTimeout` function like this.
This will not give you any

```
setTimeout(function () {
    window.parent.location.reload();
}, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

The Alert Message shows when refreshing a page in IE by using 
That works... When you want to refresh the parent page.

This might be a valid soultion:

```
window.opener.location.href = window.opener.location.href;
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem while calling modal window.
I removed `location.reload` and just returned `true` value from the function.
This solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had something totally unrelated reloading the page, someone put some javascript code to reload the page in case of resize and it was always being triggered on document.ready, making it do the post request twice, so if none of the solutions here work just make sure that there isn't some random javascript reloading the page without you knowing about it, may be useful press F12 and check the network tab to see if something unexpected is being called.